# what is the best way to work with Images in SqLite android?

Tags: android

I am working with a customizable database with pictures. Right now I am taking pictures as it is from the sdcard and encoding it in `base64` String and then putting it in the database. but whenever I am trying decoding it and showing it in my view, I am getting `Out of memory error`. Can any one one tell me what is the best procedure to do it? Shall I change the size of the pictures before encoding it?

I want to `re-size` all of the pictures into `512*512`.

Comment: yes resize the bitmap while storing in the database itself, btw why do you need to store the bitmap, can't you just store a URI instead?

Comment: You can use `cloudinary` `cdn` to upload the image their and save the image id so whenever you want to fetch the image you can fetch by image id.

Answer (score 3):

`Image` to `Base64` is very heavy operation in android. Consider saving the images on the external/internal memory and save the file path in the `sqlite` database.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your image to byte array then store values in sql by using BLOB type and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you want to resize the images to 512*512, you can scale the image using below code,
Create bitmap from captured image and then use below line

```
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 512, 512, false);
```

It will give you a smaller image, you can also consider compressing the image to reduce in size,

```
OutputStream imagefile = new FileOutputStream("/your/file/name.jpg");
// Write 'bitmap' to file using JPEG and 50% quality hint for JPEG:
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, imagefile);
```

Now, you have two options,

1. Save the scaled and compressed image into a file and save the path of that file in db. (Better way)
2. Convert the scaled and compressed image to base64 string and save in db.

Answer (score 0):

Althought base64 is , as many answers said, a heavy operation for android, if done properly, it should not be a problem.

There are many reasons a bitmap could be required to be saved to a DB , (photo of a invoice ticket, for example?), and this is the way i do it.

first, create a new , smaller bitmap like @Swapnil commented.

and second, correctly use the bitmap transformation methods, i've been using these (look below) two so far and haven't had any memory issue on many different devices.

[link to my BitmapUtils transformation methods](https://github.com/tryadelion/EricUtils/blob/master/EricUtils/ericutils2/src/main/java/com/software/cpteric/ericutils/BitmapUtils.java)